# What is this bird?

Tags: hanasaku-iroha

In Hana-Saku Iroha there's always a big bird that appear

[image]

At first I thought it's like a god or something, but as far as I know it didn't do anything. What is this bird? and what is its role?

Comment: ...it's just a bird (specifically, a Grey Heron / _aosagi_). Its role is being a bird. This is what most birds do.

Comment: @senshin well, most bird didn't interact with any character in almost every episode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a common Dutch bird called Reiger from the Ardeidae family also called [Grey Heron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_Heron) in english.

Their most common recognition points are

- Blue/grayish back
- White Belly
- Long and sturdy beaks
- A long neck that gets subtrackd in flight
- From head to chest there is a long black stroke
- Black strokes on the forehead of the bird
- On his hind side there are some gracefull black feathers

[image]

**EDIT**

The episode is called Grey Heron Rhapsody, considering the meaning of Rhapsody

> an effusively enthusiastic or ecstatic expression of feeling.

It would most likely mean the author expresses his feelings about the animal.

Comment: and what is it doing in anime? is it just for some funny moment? or maybe there's something behind it?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Sorry, overlooked that part of the question. Edited my answer. Hope it is satisfactionary.

Comment: Grey Herons are common around Japan, especially in the rural country side where this story is taking place. Ohana is not use to seeing one in the wild, outside of a zoo.